# Audit Log to Figure out which user changed "Who can edit the membership of the group" within a group's settings

Tags: sharepoint-online, groups, sharepoint-permissions

I am looking to track the setting change that a group owner can make on their groups, changing the radio button selection of "who can edit the membership of the group?" from "Group Owner" to "Group Members"?

Answer (score 1):

Good day!

I think in your case you want to know who did that historically? Unless you have the audit settings correctly established I don't think you will be able to do that.

To make sure you are good for the future:

1. Navigate to the desired site
2. In the site settings, make sure that Reporting is on.
3. Site Settings Audit Logs Reports, than security settings

You will need to filter and navigate the excel sheet. But there you should be able to see all the security changes that were made.

**UPDATE...**

Can you check under Site Settings -> Site Collection Audit Settings -> Editing users and permissions.

Let me know if that is ticked. Than try doing that with another security group what you described in your message and see if that is captured.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Kyle, thanks so much for your input. I want to confirm that these options are active, and had been activated previous to the change we are trying to find. When i run the audit log, I don't see entries for the change of who can edit group membership. the only entries i see in that audit log are for group member creation/deletion and items like that. I don't think this log records the change i'm talking about. let me know if you have any more ideas and thanks again!

Comment: I may have another idea, but admit-tingly it may not work. Check my original post for the update.

Comment: Thanks again for the update Kyle. I attempted this on a dev site collection and it appears that it is not logged within the report still. Any backend areas i could access to see this information change in a log?